# My Javascript is not working in localhost XAMPP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  hope someone can help my project school. I have a piece of HTML code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tambah Guru</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js' charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
<body>

Email: <input type='text' id='txtemail' />

<input type='submit' value='Simpan' id='validateemail' />
</body>
</html>
```

And then my Javascript code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#validateemail').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#txtemail').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

when I run it, it does not work. I don't know why. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What part *does not work*?

Comment: For one he's not including jquery.

Comment: Include jquery.js on your page as per [jQuery.com's instructions](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). If it still doesn't work, please clarify what you mean by "not work": specify the desired behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not adding jQuery as in the above comments. Put this line above your script line in html

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then you are not passing in the event object to be handled. Pass the event object in the click handler like in the code below. You are passing the event handler in the document.ready which is not you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#validateemail').click(function(e) {
        var sEmail = $('#txtemail').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert('Email is valid');
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining. Learning a lot from you people :)

Comment: thans for explaining :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jquery.js file as it is a Javascript library. You can either download and include it or simply use this url in script tag:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is a better option as it has many advantages like decreased latency, increased parallelism, and better caching.

Comment: atleast review when copy pasting other's answers. I didn't add a colon after http and now edited it. Edit your answer to include it

Comment: @shadowmonkey That is understandable. Isn't it ?

Comment: it indeed is. But when you post an answer, atleast consider revising it because not everyone is of the same skill level or there are times when you and I have stuck for hours on sth silly :) Just saying.

Comment: Wait, was this (pre-edited) answer just a copy of the other answer?

Comment: @nnnnnn The script tag was from what I understand as he just had the same mistake I had on the url ;)

Comment: No, but the URL was the same. I see no wrong here, as both parties probably copied it from somewhere and added notes regarding the issue. If i remember correctly, google omits the http: as to not force SSL/non-SSL

Comment: @DavidHoude - Fair enough. This answer does provide additional information about why you'd use the Google CDN. (It was just that reading between the lines of the first two comments it sounded like "You copied my answer." "Yes I did.")

Comment: @nnnnnn I may have been a bit of douche over there. But, primary intention was to put in the correct script URL. But yeah adding the CDN was informative.